# How to divide Loader operations to React Remix child components?

Tags: react-typescript, remix.run

React Remix has [loader functions](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/loader) that runs on the server and returns data to the client on render and accessed via [`useLoaderData()`](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-loader-data). In my use I have a rather slow loader that runs that I've have been attempting to reduce sluggishness on the app. The browsers seem to recommend keeping individual requests under 500ms. Mine is slightly above that:
[image: network request]
[image]

I have added this [defer](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/utils/defer) to return defer responses that help the overall experience but the network request remains over 500ms but instead of only "Waiting" some of the time is spend "Receiving":
[image]

For this call I deferred a call to a function that grabs team invites a user has called `getUsersPendingInvitations()` that can be loaded async for the user. The data received from this call is passed to a child react component and the child displays the content as intended. But the package is still bundled into a single network call on the browser so regardless of how much a break up and defer these API calls, the browser will still view it as slow.

The only option might be using `<Outlet />` and change the child component into it's own route to allow it to have a loader function that runs on the child component but at that point it is more like a child route than a component and I don't unsure if that is even what I want since ideally I could just drop the child component wherever I need in my application and allow it to run it's loader without worrying about folder structure and routing.
I have tried playing with the [`useFetcher()`](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-fetcher#fetcherload) to call a loader function from the component directly but with no success, though I might be viewing this incorrectly.

I am running remix-run version 1.5.1 in this application.

**Is it possible to split the loader data into multiple network calls in the react child component itself?**

Below is my code I have so far.

parent component index.tsx:

```
import { Await, useLoaderData, useNavigate } from "@remix-run/react"
import teamsPageStyles from "~/styles/teams.css"
import type { LinksFunction, LoaderArgs} from "@remix-run/node"
import { defer } from "@remix-run/node"
import { AssignedTeams } from "./components/assignedTeams"
import { checkForPost, getUsersPendingInvitations, getUid } from "~/firebase-db.server"
import { getUser, getUserTeams } from "~/db.server"
import { TeamInvitations } from "./components/teamInvitations"
import { Suspense } from "react"

export const links: LinksFunction = () => {
    return [{ rel: "stylesheet", href: teamsPageStyles }]
}

export const loader = async ({ request }: LoaderArgs) => {
    const uid = await getUid(request)
    const [ user, teams ] = await Promise.all([getUser(uid), getUserTeams(uid)])
    const pendingTeamInvites = getUsersPendingInvitations(request)
    const day = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA')
    const promises = teams.map(async (team, i) => {
        const slug = team.slug
        const postStatus = await checkForPost(slug, day, uid)
        const teamItem = {
            teamId: team.slug,
            postStatus: postStatus
        }
        return teamItem
    })

    const teamAndPostStatus = await Promise.all(promises)
    return defer({ user, teams, teamAndPostStatus,
        pendingTeamInvites })
}


export default function TeamsHomePage() {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>()
    const {teams, teamAndPostStatus, pendingTeamInvites} = data
    return (
        <div className="teams-home">
            <div className="teams-header">
                <h3>All Teams</h3>
                <button className="create-button" onClick={() => navigate("./create")}>Create a Team +</button>
            </div>
            <div className="invitations-list list-container">
                <ul>
                    <Suspense>
                        <Await 
                            resolve={pendingTeamInvites}
                            errorElement={<p>Error loading invitations</p>}>
                            {(pendingTeamInvites) => (
                                pendingTeamInvites.map(invite => <TeamInvitations key={invite.inviteObj.inviteTimeStamp} invite={invite}/>)
                            )}
                        </Await>
                    </Suspense>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="list-container">
                <ul>
                    <AssignedTeams teams={teams} teamAndPostStatus={teamAndPostStatus} />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Child component teamInvitations.tsx:

```
import { useFetcher } from "@remix-run/react"
import { useState } from "react"
import type { docIDandInvite } from "~/types/team"

export function TeamInvitations({invite} : {invite: docIDandInvite}) {
    const fetcher = useFetcher()
    
    const [inviteAcceptanceStatusState, setInviteAcceptanceStatus] = useState('')
    return (
        <>
            <fetcher.Form action='../../../forms/replyToTeamInvite' method='post' className="teams-header">
                <h3>You are invited to {invite.inviteObj.teamSlug}</h3>
                <button className="create-button" onClick={() => setInviteAcceptanceStatus('accepted')}>Accept invite</button>
                <button className="create-button" onClick={() => setInviteAcceptanceStatus('rejected')}>Decline invite</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="inviteAcceptanceStatus" value={inviteAcceptanceStatusState} />
                <input type="hidden" name="inviteObj" value={JSON.stringify(invite)} />
            </fetcher.Form>
        </>
    )
}
```